# Is CORS or JSONP Required (Angular JS)

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Here's the deployment scenario ,  `skeleton` HTML pages with `AngularJS` will be served by a plain HTTP Server (like Apache). However these pages will make  AJAX call to an Application Server (JBoss) hosting Spring Controller. These controllers will serve contents that will be rendered in the HTML pages.

Both these servers will be on same domain. Do I need to worry about `CORS` or `JSONP`? Will routine AJAX call work.

Please advise

Comment: I think that the question you should ask is if you need to worry from the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), because the 2 things that you mentioned are means to circumvent that policy.

Comment: You can use both apache and nginx as reverse proxies to your backend, and map your api into a local path and then you do not have to worry about cors or jsonp, you can just use normal ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

CORS and JSONP are means to circumvent the Same Origin Policy.

You need to circumvent it if the document the script runs in is on a different origin to the resource you are trying to access with JavaScript.

For two resources to be on the same origin they need to share:

- Protocol
- Host
- Port

Since you are running two different servers, and you can't have two servers listening on the same port, then they aren't sharing all three of those factors so you will need a mechanism to circumvent the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Thanks this clarifies my doubt, so I need to think about CORS or JSONP